# Django can't see my validator

Tags: python, django, validation

I want to use my own custom-made validator. The problem is, Django can't see the validator.

models.py:

```
class Market(models.Model):
    money = models.DecimalField(max_digits = 15, decimal_places=2, validators=[moneyValidator])

D = decimal.Decimal

def moneyValidator(x):
    if not convStr(x):
        raise ValidationError
    if (x <= 0) or (x >= PAYOFF) or (D(str(x))%D('0.01') != 0):
        raise ValidationError

def convStr(x):
    try:
        str(x)
        return True
    except ValueError:
        return False
```

Error message:

```
NameError: name 'moneyValidator' is not defined
```

I think what's going on is that Django calls this from wherever and doesn't know where to look for the function. What can I do about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method `moneyValidator` should be declared before the class declaration:

```
def moneyValidator(x):
    ...

class Market(models.Model):
    money = models.DecimalField(max_digits = 15, decimal_places=2, validators=[moneyValidator])
```

Comment: It seems like Python actually cares of it.

Comment: @oneloop: in *functions* global names are not looked up until the function is called, which is why you can define other functions later. But a class definition is executed there and then and names like validators have to be available at that time.